# std::bind to std::function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, bind, std

I get a compile error using this:

```
std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> functions;

std::function<int(int, int)> foo = [](int a, int b){ return a + b; };
std::function<int(int)> bar = std::bind(foo, 2);

functions.push_back(bar);
```

The error is:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1764:40: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind(int)>) (int)'

Can someone tell me how to convert a `std::bind` into a `std::function`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
std::function<int(int)> bar = std::bind(foo, 2, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: ` std::bind(foo, 2, std::placeholders::_1)` is equal to ` std::bind(foo, 2,)` ?

Comment: @BlackMamba I think you are getting confused about which function has 2 parameters. A placeholder other than _1 implies the **bind result** has more than 1 parameter

Comment: This is the second Q/A I've came across this week that where the provided answer had used `std::placeholders::...` and before this week I was not familiar with it. It's always good to learn something new.